# Random Number JavaScript In Span Tag

Tags: javascript, html, random, numbers

I'm trying to create a random number in a span tag, how would I go about doing this? I've been trying but I'm sure I'm missing something.

```
<div><span id="people">2 </span>Is a random number</div>
```

and my JS is

```
window.onload = myFunction() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 2);
    document.getElementById("people").innerHTML = x;
}
```

Comment: Change `myFunction()` to `function()`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something the OP could easily have found out him/herself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a syntax error when you define an anonymous function:

```
// -------------v
window.onload = function() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 2);
    document.getElementById("people").innerHTML = x;
};
```

If you want to give a name for your anonymous function you may do:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 2);
    document.getElementById("people").innerHTML = x;
}

window.onload = myFunction;
```

Answer (score 1):

To create an anonymous function in an [expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function), use `function() {...}`, like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 2);
    document.getElementById("people").innerHTML = x;
}
```

Alternatively, to use a named function, it would look like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 2);
    document.getElementById("people").innerHTML = x;
}

window.onload = myFunction;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an syntax error in your `anonymous` function

Replace

`myFunction()`

with

`function()`

Rest of your code is error free.